# How to take irfft of multidimensional array in julia?

Tags: arrays, julia, fft

I am new to julia, and I am trying to take the irfft of B, which is a 3d array of size (n/2, n, n) where B = rfft(A). However, the irfft in julia reqires an additional input d for the size of the transformed real array, and I'm unsure of what to put. I tried n and n/2, but both did not seem to work as expected when I printed the resulting matrix out.

EDIT: I should've lowered my dimensions to check if everything was working, turns out using d = n is ok. Thanks to everyone who answered!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this discussion](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/intended-behaviour-of-irfft/11945). Presumably any triple of numbers will do the trick, but may or may not give you what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, the API specifies that d must be an integer. I tried putting in (64, 128, 128) in the place of d (n = 128 in this case) and it doesn't work. I also have tried just putting in 128 for d, but when i print out what that equals it enters an infinite loop, saying that i have Excessive output after some point for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
using FFTW

function test(n = 16)
    a = rand(n ÷ 2, n, n)
    f = rfft(a)
    @show irfft(f, n ÷ 2 + 1)
end

test()
```